# OSquery - How to preload data to find infected files

Tags: baseline, osquery

I have to 'take over' some already infected windows workstations and servers during a cyber exercise.
Plan is to setup eg. a clean windows 7 workstations with latest patches ... then update the infected workstation 7 to latest patches ... load osquery data (file checksums, file owner/group, permissions, etc.) and check the infected workstation against this know-good 'baseline'.
is there a good way to do this with osquery or do your recommend another tool for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "load osquery data", but you can use osquery to query that information for sure. For example, the following will allow you to get file information (including permissions, owner, etc) for all files on user's download directory:

```
select * from file where path like '/Users/user/Downloads/%';
```

If you want hashes you can query the `hash` table:

```
select * from hash where path like '/Users/user/Downloads/%';
```

Comment: maybe to clarify:
I want to create OSquery file info (hash, size, permissions, etc.) on a clean, fresh installed system and use that data to find altered/trojanized files on a different system (both systems have same OS/patch_level of course).
is that possible at all...?

Comment: You can use osquery to query the info on the clean machine and then craft queries to find differences, say query the hash table like `select * from hash where path = '<myfile> and md5 != '<known_hash>';`. But osquery doesn't have any functionality to compare results with a baseline.

Answer (score 0):

This should be do-able, but your question is pretty broad. Getting a baseline of what a known good Windows 7 system looks like is gunna depend a lot on what you care about. What I'd recommend doing would be to get some json dumps of the tables you think might matter for your specific investigation, so perhaps something like:

```
PS C:\Users\thor\Desktop> osqueryi --json -A drivers
PS C:\Users\thor\Desktop> osqueryi --json -A programs
PS C:\Users\thor\Desktop> osqueryi --json -A users
PS C:\Users\thor\Desktop> osqueryi --json -A startup_items
PS C:\Users\thor\Desktop> osqueryi --json "select f.filename, f.path, h.md5, h.sha256 from file f, hash h where h.path = f.path and f.path like 'C:\Windows\%';"
PS C:\Users\thor\Desktop> osqueryi --json "select f.filename, f.path, h.md5, h.sha256 from file f, hash h where h.path = f.path and f.path like 'C:\Windows\system32\%%';"
PS C:\Users\thor\Desktop> osqueryi --json -A scheduled_tasks
PS C:\Users\thor\Desktop> osqueryi --json -A certificates
```

**Note** this definitely isn't an exhaustive list, but just some things that might be good to check. I'd also recommend adding in the queries @fmanco mentioned above.

Once you've built out a hefty list of JSON blobs with data from the baseline system, you can then run the same queries against the compromised system and "diff" the json outputs looking for differences. This can get really tricky, especially when considering hashes of C:\Windows\system32\%% files, considering the hash values can vary drastically even on the same patch version of the system, just fyi.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You may be interesting in https://github.com/Netflix-Skunkworks/diffy

It's a tool designed to compare differences between hosts.